# How to stack labels

Tags: labeling

How can labels be stacked?  The data has multiple points stacked at the same point location.  All of the labels from all of the points at one location need to be stacked in a list next to the "group" point.

Answer (score 2):

between field values you can use

```
&vbnewline&
```

More solutions for arcmap 9.x
[Labelstacker](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=15608)

Mapperz has some links in this answer [Place overlapping](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3456/display-labels-for-all-point-features-in-arcgis)

this answer may also show some helpful concepts.
[labeling by class](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6252/labeling-classes-for-small-roads-on-large-extent-maps-in-arcmap-with-sql-statemen/6271#6271)

I recently built a complex label for multiple points (stacked on top or close proximity) using maplex.
It will take some time to layout but if you are interested I will post and edit this later.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the script in the link, but vbnewline won't work here if I understand the question correctly. Yorkmapper is looking to stack labels from different points in a layer that happen to share the same coordinates, not stacking fields or text in a label from a single point feature. I don't know of a way to automate it in a nice list way w/o doing so manually, although again, maybe the linked script can do it.
My apologies if I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: no apology necessary, OP hasn't mentioned the software we have all been assuming ESRI. many ways to inturpret stacked labels.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you have access to ArcGIS)  Bert Granberg over at the Utah GIS Portal put a pretty lengthy label expression together that looks to fit the bill.

Original post can be found here:  [Utah GIS Portal](http://gis.utah.gov/code-arcmap-label-cal-scripts/vb-script-label-expression-for-multiple-line-labels-in-arcmap)

```
Function FindLabel ( [Name] )

Dim strArray
Dim outStr
Dim x
Dim maxWordLength
Dim minLengthLength
Dim everyother
Dim isFirst
Dim lastWordLong
lastWordLong = false

maxWordLength = 10
minWordLength = 3
everyother = False
isFirst = True
strArray = Split( [Name], " ")

For x = 0 To UBound(strArray)

    If ((Not isFirst) And (Len(strArray(x)) <= minWordLength)) Then
        'keep short word on existing line
        outStr = outStr & " " & strArray(x)
        everyother = False
    ElseIf (everyother) Then
        'word x is slated to be second word on line
        If (Len(strArray(x)) > maxWordLength) Then
            outStr = outStr & vbNewLine & strArray(x)
            everyother = False
        Else
            outStr = outStr & " " & strArray(x)
            everyother = False
        End If
    Else
        'word x is slated to be first word on line
        If (isFirst) Then
            outStr = strArray(x)
            everyother = True
            isFirst = False
        Else
            If (Len(strArray(x)) > maxWordLength) Then
                lastWordLong = True
                everyother = False
            Else
                lastWordLong = False
                everyother = True
            End If

            outStr = outStr & vbNewLine & strArray(x)

        End If
    End If
Next

FindLabel = outStr
```

End Function

Comment: Just noticed that your post mentioned multiple points at a single location.  The solution I've offered is appropriate for a large text string of a single feature to be parsed in code...